# Check date is available or not in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image]

i have datepicker like this, current date selected is 02/06/2015 as per image , if i click "+1 Day" then it should through error "Date is Unavailable", because 03/06/2015 is unavailable or disabled.

can anyone did this before, please suggest answer.

Comment: Max date should be specify then never to select max date after any date

Comment: it does not do anything with maxDate i think!!! if anyone click "+1 Day" i want to check wheather next day is available or not ie., disabled or not, similarly to "+1 Week" and "+1 Month" too , is there any way to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just done an example. I must override some methods, do some tricks. Hope this help. Demo below.

```js
$(function() {
  var beforeShowFunction = function(input, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget")
        .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
      var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">+</button>');
      btn.bind("click", function(e) {
        if ($(input).datepicker('getDate') == null)
          return;
        var currentDate = new Date($(input).datepicker("getDate"));
        var newDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1));
        $(input).datepicker("setDate", newDate);
        currentDate = new Date($(input).datepicker("getDate"));
        if (currentDate.getDate() != newDate.getDate()) {
          alert('Unavailabled!');
        }
        $(input).datepicker("hide");
        $(input).datepicker("show");
      });
      btn.appendTo(buttonPane);
      var btnMinus = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">-</button>');
      btnMinus.bind("click", function(e) {
        if ($(input).datepicker('getDate') == null)
          return;
        var currentDate = new Date($(input).datepicker("getDate"));
        var newDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1));
        $(input).datepicker("setDate", newDate);
        currentDate = new Date($(input).datepicker("getDate"));
        if (currentDate.getDate() != newDate.getDate()) {
          alert('Unavailabled!');
        }
        $(input).datepicker("hide");
        // force call show to see +, - buttons 
        $(input).datepicker("show");
      });
      btnMinus.appendTo(buttonPane);
    }, 1);
  };

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: -20,
    maxDate: "+1M +10D",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: beforeShowFunction,
  });
  // Below fix today button 
  jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
    var target = jQuery(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
      inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
      inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
      inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    } else {
      var date = new Date();
      inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
      inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
      inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
      this._setDateDatepicker(target, date);
      this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
    }
    this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustDate(target);
    // force call show to see +, - buttons
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("show");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<br />
```

Comment: you had added +1day and  -1day, but i have done that already. what i want to know is, whether there is anyway to check  next day (next day after selected day) is active or not disabled. can you guide me in that?

Comment: I add date range. If you choose the the min/max days of rang, and click +/- button, it can change the date. It should be better than show an alert message to user. If you still want to show message, after call setDate(newDate), you should call getDate to get currentDate and compare newDate with currentDate to show message.

Answer (score -1):

you can check if the input date is valid date for example:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse("33-01-2014", out d);
```

you can also add day

```
d.AddDays(1);
```

and check if the month change or whatever...

Comment: please read my question its not much about validation, i want check a date is available or not ie., disabled or not

Comment: lets put in this way, current date is "02/06/2015" as per image, i want to check "03/06/2015" is clickable or not

Comment: what the rules for it availability? not weekends?

Comment: no its not only weekend, i have some scheduled days other days i set as disabled days

Comment: so only you know what the rules need to be check if the user add more day to the current selected date... you need to create your own logic for this...